# Update master uitableview from detail view when tap back button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a master ItemTableViewController which contains long list of item. On every cell, there's a "Mark as favorite" UIButton which will turn red when pushed, and gray when not pushed. Each cell can also be tapped, and pushed to ItemDetailViewController.

Meanwhile, ItemDetailViewController also has a "Mark as favorite" UIButton.

How can I update ItemTableViewController's cell to red if I do this :
1. Tap on one of ItemTableViewController's cell that has not been favorited yet, and go to ItemDetailViewController
2. Tap on Mark as Favorite button
3. Tap back button

I know i can do [self reloadData] in viewWillAppear. But I will lose the latest scroll position and I don't want that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, track the cell index with `NSIndexPath *clickedIndexPath = indexPath` and when returning to view, do

`NSArray *reloadPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:@[indexPath];`

`[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: reloadPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationDefault];`